# Capture output of curl after a string to a file

Tags: text-processing, command-line, sed, grep

I would like to output everything after the string "director-services" to a file from a bash script.

```
$ curl localhost:9201/_cat/health
1472487809 12:23:29 director-services green 3 3 828 276 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using combination of `grep` and `cut`,

```
$ curl ... | grep -o "director-services.*" | cut -d' ' -f2- 
green 3 3 828 276 0 0 0 0
```

or simply using `perl`,

```
$ curl ... |  perl -lne 'print $1 if /director-services (.*)/'
green 3 3 828 276 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: OP wants what comes after so you could use `cut` to complete your answer: `curl ... | grep -o "director-services.*" | cut -d' ' -f2-` > output`.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are using ElasticSearch with the `_cat` API for querying cluster parameters.

You don't need any external processing tool, the `_cat` API has header matching capabilities with matching metacharacters while using the `?h=` query.

As you need to get everything starting from column header `node.total`, you can use:

```
_cat/health?h=node.total,*
```

**Example:**

```
% curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/health'               
1472532922 00:55:22 foobar red 1 1 3279 3279 0 0 3190 0 - 50.7% 

% curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/health?v'
epoch      timestamp cluster status node.total node.data shards  pri relo init unassign pending_tasks max_task_wait_time active_shards_percent 
1472532925 00:55:25  foobar  red             1         1   3279 3279    0    0     3190             0                  -                 50.7% 

% curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/health?h=node.total,*'
1 1472532942 00:55:42 foobar red 1 3279 3279 0 0 3190 0 - 50.7%
```